# ruby pipes, IO and stderr redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pipe

I am looking to have a ruby program (a rake task) observe an output from another rake task. The output writer outputs to stderr. I'd like to read those lines. I'm having difficulty setting it up. If I have a writer (stdout_writer.rb) that constantly prints something:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'writing...'
while true
  $stdout.puts '~'
  sleep 1
end
```

and a file that reads it and echoes (stdin_reader.rb):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts 'reading...'
while input = ARGF.gets
  puts input
  input.each_line do |line|
    begin
      $stdout.puts "got line #{line}"
    rescue Errno::EPIPE
      exit(74)
    end
  end
end
```

and I'm trying to have them work together, nothing happens:

```
$ ./stdout_writer.rb 2>&1 | ./stdin_reader.rb
$ ./stdout_writer.rb | ./stdin_reader.rb
```

nothing... although if I just echo into stdin_reader.rb, I get what I expect:

```
piousbox@e7440:~/projects/opera_events/sendgrid-example-operaevent$ echo "ok true" | ./stdin_reader.rb
reading...
ok true
got line ok true
piousbox@e7440:~/projects/opera_events/sendgrid-example-operaevent$
```

so how would I setup a script that gets stderr piped into it, so that it can read it line-by-line? Additional info: this will be an ubuntu upstart service `script1.rb | script2.rb` where script1 sends a message, and script2 verifies that the message was sent by script1

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that as `stdout_writer` runs infinitely, `stdin_reader` will never get a chance to read the `STDOUT` from `stdout_writer` as the pipe, in this case, is waiting for `stdout_writer` to be finished before `stdin_reader` starts reading. I tested this by changing `while true` to `5.times do`. If you do that, and wait 5 seconds, the result of `./stdout_writer.rb | ./stdin_reader.rb` is

```
reading...
writing...
got line writing...
~
got line ~
~
got line ~
~
got line ~
~
got line ~
~
got line ~
```

This isn't an issue with your code itself, but more so an issue with the way that ruby execution in terms of `STDOUT | STDIN` handling works.

Also, I don't think I've ever learned as much as I learned researching this question. Thank you for the fun exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The output from `stdout_writer.rb` is being buffered by Ruby, so the reader process doesn’t see it. If you wait long enough, you should see the result appear in chunks.

You can turn buffering off and get the result you’re expecting by [setting `sync` to true](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D) on `$stdout` at the start of stdout_writer.rb:

```
$stdout.sync = true
```